# Why do i get an empty list when i look for numbers with regular expressions

Tags: python, filehandle, python-re

So i've been doing an online python course and one of the assignements has me look throught a text file, find all the numbers, and print out the total sum, i am able to retrieve all the numbers however my code also returns empty lists, here's the code:

```
import re
handle = open('words.txt')

for line in handle:
    line = line.strip()
    numbers = re.findall('[1-9]+', line)
    print(numbers)
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You might want to use `[0-9]+` if you want to match `10`. You will get an empty list every time a line doesn't contain any numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `\d+` (digits):

```
numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', line)
```

As for your existing regex, might be because you are missing 0 (`[0-9]+`).